# Wordpress Require Login

Tags: php, wordpress, post, authentication, get

I have some restricted content on a WordPress site. What I want is pretty simple (I think). If a user is not logged in, redirect to the `/login` page with an error like "You must be logged in to view this content". The problem is that I don't know what GET (or POST) request variables are to accomplish this. Is there an error_message variable  or even a login_required variable or anything I can set to make this happen? I have Googled this, but can't seem to find much.

```
if( !is_user_logged_in() ){
    wp_redirect('/login?error_message=ERRORMESSAGEHERE&redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.dev%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1');
}
```

NOTE: I would much prefer to avoid using any plugins to accomplish this. Although recommending plugins is... ok, it's not the solution I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think there is no default GET/POST parameter for this in Wordpress itself but what you are looking for seems to be part of the theme anyway.

Go to path/to/wordpress/wp-content/themes/yourtheme/header.php

And add something linke this at the end:

```
if($_GET['error_message']){
  echo '<div class="errormessage"> <strong>Error: </strong> '.htmlentities($_GET['error_message']).'</div>';
}
```

You can easily use CSS to style your "error-box". Note that the "htmlentites" is necessary to prevent XSS attacks on your site.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm afraid this is not the functionality I'm looking for. I would like the error message to appear on the WordPress login page, not on the page the user is attempting to access. That would be an easy fix, as you have shown, by simply editing my theme. Since this issue involves the WordPress core, I need to find a way pass it the proper variable, without the need to edit wp-login.php.

Comment: So you want the common "not authorized" message to show up on the /wp-login page, right?

Comment: I just tried that on my WP setup. The login page uses POST parameters `wp-submit`,`log` and `pwd`. If these are "wrong" the message will show up. But there is no special Parameter added to indicate that this message should show up. So you may usa a "dirty" solution and change `$_POST` in `$_REQUEST` in your `wp-login.php` and refer to `/wp-login?wp-submit=false&log=false&pwd=false`

Answer (score 0):

After some more digging, I found [this over on wordpress.stackexchange.com](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14250/creating-custom-login-errors). Below is an example of what I may ended up using:

**page-templates/custom-template.php:**

```
if( !is_user_logged_in() ){
    wp_redirect('/login?err=err1&redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.dev%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1');
}
```

**functions.php:**

```
add_action('login_head','custom_errors');
function custom_errors() {
    global $error;
    if( !empty($_GET['err']) ){
        $err = $_GET['err'];
        switch ($err) {
            case 'err1': $error = 'Error 1'; break;
            case 'err2': $error = 'Error 2'; break;
        }
    }
}
```